# vb.netで作成したプログラムが強制終了されてしまう。

Tags: windows, vb.net

お世話になっております。
閲覧ありがとうございます。

以下の原因が分かる方いらっしゃいましたら、
教えて頂きたく、質問させていただきます。

開発言語：VB.net
開発環境：Visual Studio 2017
プログラム概要：指定ディレクトリ以下、全てのファイル情報をDBに登録する。
ファイル情報：ファイル名、ファイルパス、サイズ、更新日時、登録日時、内容
ファイル内容の取得方法：テキストコンバータを使用しています。(xdoc2txt)

プログラムとしての機能は、正常に動作していることを確認済みです。
各処理で、例外が発生した場合はログ出力を行っています。
しかし、不意にアプリが強制終了されることがあり、その際はログ出力がされません。
Windowsのイベントビューアにて確認を行ったところ以下のような例外コードが発生していることが分かりました。

例外コード: 0xc0000409

私なりに調べて、WindowsDefenderの無効化を行ってみたのですが、結果が変わることはありませんでした。
分かる方いらっしゃいましたらお教えください。

[追記]
進歩があったため、報告させていただきます。
特定のファイルで強制終了となってしまいます。
xdoc2txtのExtractTextで強制終了となっていることも分かりました。
ファイルに原因があることは分かったのですが、ExtractTextのソースを見ることが出来ないため、強制終了を逃れることが出来ません。
分かる方いらっしゃいましたらお教えください。

Comment: まずはどの処理で強制終了されているかの特定をしてみてはどうでしょうか。ソースに手を入れることが可能であれば、すべての関数の入り口、出口にログを出力するようにして処理を追い、特定の個所で落ちるようでしたら、その処理が怪しいですし、落ちる場所がまちまちだったら、メモリの使い方(使いすぎていないか、等)を検討するなど対策が立てやすくなると思います。

Comment: Sugiyama-Koichi様、ご返信ありがとうございます。
もう少し調査を続けて解決できるように試みます。
重ねて質問させて頂きたいのですが、
10万件以上のファイルを対象としていまして、数万件登録された時点で処理が終了してしまいます。メモリの使い過ぎが原因であると考えるべきでしょうか？

Comment: 処理やデータ内容を見ないとはっきりしたことは何も言えないですが、10万件というのは1ファイルに10万件以上データが入っているということですか？それとも処理対象のファイルが10万件ある、ということでしょうか。どちらにせよ全てを一度に読み込んで処理をしているのであれば、その設計を見直すことも必要になるかもしれません。

Comment: Sugiyama-Koichi様、ご返信ありがとうございます。
対象フォルダに10万件以上のファイルがあり、1件1件登録している状態です。
追記させてもらったのですが、あるファイルで強制終了されることが分かりました。テキストコンバータ内の関数内でアプリが落ちてしまっているようでして、このような場合の対処法はありますか？

Answer (score 1):

`STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN`の値が`0xC0000409`です。つまりバッファオーバーランが発生したことによりスタックが破壊されている可能性があります。スタックは関数の呼び出し・戻りにも使われているので、ここが破壊されると関数呼び出しが一切信用できなくなりプログラムの実行を継続することは困難です。ですのでプロセスが停止されイベントログが記録されている可能性があります。

追記が正しいのであれば`xdoc2txt`の`ExtractText`が原因なのでしょう。`xdoc2txt`作者に報告し、修正してもらうのが最良かと思われます。

Comment: sayuri様、ご返信ありがとうございます。私と同じような現象の方が記した記事を見ました。特定のpdfファイルはテキスト変換が行えずに、強制終了されてしまうみたいです。pdfファイルに関しては、他のアプローチ方法で開発を進めようと思います。